# Automating keyboard buttons inside of input outputs NONE

Tags: python, input, automation, keyboard, pynput

I hope everyone is having a wonderful day.

I am practicing using pynput. I came into a block.

When I tell my keyboard to type into an input, the results have whatever I told it plus a None.

Input:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import time

keyboard = Controller()

keyboard.press(Key.alt)
keyboard.press('4')
keyboard.release(Key.alt)
keyboard.release('4')

path = "Test Test 123"

def type_enter():
    keyboard.type(path)
    time.sleep(1)
    keyboard.press(Key.enter)
    keyboard.release(Key.enter)

x = input(type_enter())
```

Output:

```
Test Test 123
None
```

Anyone knows what is happening?

Thank you so much in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The optional argument for `input()` is mainly for posing questions, not for receiving answers. As described [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input), "If the prompt argument is present, it is written to standard output without a trailing newline. The function then reads a line from input, converts it to a string (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that."

What happened here is that `input()` interpreted the output of `type_enter()` as a string to display in the process of posing a question to the user. `type_enter()` doesn't have a return statement, so it returns `None` by default, which is then taken to be the string argument to `input()`.

### Edit:

It looks like the problem you mentioned in your comment is that it's waiting until the input line finishes executing before proceeding to the typing line. This can be solved by putting the typing line in its own thread, so it runs in parallel to the input line.

Try this:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import time
import threading

keyboard = Controller()

def type_enter():
    time.sleep(1)
    keyboard.type("Test Test 123")
    time.sleep(1)
    keyboard.press(Key.enter)
    keyboard.release(Key.enter)

thread = threading.Thread(target=type_enter)
thread.start()
x = input()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining it. The code attached does not work, since then I do need to manually type something and press enter to start the next line.

If what I understood from you, I need to make sure I have a return statement that returns a value. right?

Comment: @Osmiqa I edited my answer to fix this problem. To answer your question, no, you wouldn't need a return statement unless you want that return statement to be used to prompt the user to respond. `type_enter` should work fine without a return statement, as long as it actually types as intended.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and clear explanation. I will look into the threading since I have never seen it, but it did solve the problem.